# Incorrect widget.size() when checking before a signal

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QLineEdit class *QLineEditContext* which will contain context widgets (mostly buttons).

A list of widgets will be provided to this class, which will then be used to add the child widgets to *QLineEditContext*

What I was hoping to do was to set the textMargins on *QLineEditContext* based on the width of all the context widgets provided, so that the text input doesn't get overlapped by the context buttons being added.

My problem is that the size I query using widget.size() is always incorrect (640, 480).

However; if I try to query the size (def action() under ContextWidgets) in a slot via widget.clicked.connect(), it returns the correct size.

**QLineEdit**

```
class QLineEditContext(Qtg.QLineEdit):
'''
Create QLineEdit with a internal context buttons
'''
context_button_action = Qtc.pyqtSignal(bool)

def __init__(self, widgets = None, parent = None):
    super(QLineEditContext, self).__init__(parent)

    # Create spacer to push child widgets to the right
    spacer = Qtg.QSpacerItem(0, 0, Qtg.QSizePolicy.Expanding, Qtg.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

    # Create internal layout for child widgets
    internal_layout = Qtg.QHBoxLayout(self)

    margin = 2
    internal_layout.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)
    internal_layout.addItem(spacer)

    text_margin = 0
    # Add child widgets to this widget
    if widgets:
        for widget in widgets:
            widget.setCursor(widget.cursor()) # Force child widget to use it's default cursor, rather than the parents
            widget.setSizePolicy(Qtg.QSizePolicy.Fixed, Qtg.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            internal_layout.addWidget(widget)

            print widget.sizeHint(), widget.size()
            text_margin = text_margin + widget.sizeHint().width() + (margin * 2)

    # Create cutoff margin for text
    print text_margin
    self.setTextMargins(0, 0, text_margin, 0)
```

**ContextWidgets**

```
    ctx_a = Qtg.QPushButton('_blahblahblahblahblah_')
    ctx_a.setFixedWidth(200)        
    ctx_b = Qtg.QCheckBox()

    ctx_line_edit = QLineEditContext([ctx_b,ctx_a])

    ctx_a.clicked.connect(lambda: self.action(ctx_a))
    ctx_b.clicked.connect(lambda: self.action(ctx_b))

def action(self, me):
    print self.me.sizeHint(), self.me.size()
```

I'm unable to find anything similar to this and am stumped on what's causing this and how to get around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in my haste I provided a poor example.

Reading more into the QWidgets doc's, I've found a way to make this work using resizeEvent.

**Here's a better, working example:**

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Blah')
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.setGeometry(400, 350, 500, 350)

        # Create context widgets
        push_button = QPushButton('bleh')
        push_button.setFixedWidth(200)
        check_box = QCheckBox()

        self.sp_widget = QLineEditCtx([check_box, push_button])
        self.setCentralWidget(self.sp_widget)


class QLineEditCtx(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, widgets, parent = None):
        super(QLineEditCtx, self).__init__(parent)

        self.widgets = widgets

        # QLineEdit properties
        self.setMaximumHeight(50)

        spacer = QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)

        layout.addItem(spacer)

        for widget in widgets:
            widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            widget.setCursor(widget.cursor())
            layout.addWidget(widget)


            # THIS RETURNS THE INCORRECT SIZE
            print 'init:', widget,  widget.size()



    def resizeEvent(self, event = None):
        # THIS RETURNS THE CORRECT SIZE
        text_margin = 0

        for widget in self.widgets:
            print 'resizeEvent:',widget, widget.size()
            text_margin = text_margin + widget.size().width() + (self.layout().contentsMargins().right() *2)

        self.setTextMargins(0, 0, text_margin, 0)


# Initialize
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sp_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    sp_window = MainWindow()
    sp_window.show()

    sys.exit(sp_app.exec_())
```

Although I'm still not sure I understand why it has to be done this way.

Shouldn't it get the correct size, as long as the widget is already shown?